# gRPC: How can RPC handlers properly detect if `Server` has been `Shutdown()`

Tags: c++, qt, grpc

Current, I'm using a hackish way – a global variable – to make RPC handlers able to detect that the `Server` has been (about to be) called `Shutdown()`.

```
bool g_ServerIsNotDead = true;   // Hack!

Status StreamServiceImpl::GetCurrentTemperature(ServerContext *context_,
                                                const UpdateInterval *request_,
                                                ServerWriter<Temperature> *stream_)
{
  auto currentTemp = 100.0f;
  while(g_ServerIsNotDead)   // Hack!!!
  {
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId() << currentTemp << "farenheit.";

    Temperature message;
    message.set_temperature(currentTemp);
    stream_->Write(message);

    QThread::sleep(2);

    currentTemp += 1.0f;
  }

  return Status::OK;
}

void insideSomeFunction() {
   // Testing shutdown 5 seconds later
   QTimer::singleShot(std::chrono::seconds(5), this, [=]() {
      qDebug() << "Shuting down!";

      g_ServerIsNotDead = false;   // Hack!!

      this->server->Shutdown();    // This method actually blocks until all RPC handlers have exited, believe it or not!

      emit shutdown();

      qDebug() << "All dead.";
  });
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/C0D1UM/grpc-qt-example/blob/master/rpc_server/hellostream_server.cpp

It would be really nice if I could somehow check that `Server` has been `Shutdown()` from `grpc::ServerContext`, but I didn't see any relevant methods to achieve this.

Even better if someone could propose a way to take out the while loop completely (?). I'm using Qt so everything is event-driven.

Answer (score 5):

So, I think it's worth making clear what `Shutdown` does. There's a [detailed comment about this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/500e3399b630d60cf5b32ac3d7dd6bd403e31da4/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/server_interface.h#L52-L75) but basically, server `Shutdown` doesn't fail, cancel, or kill your existing in-progress calls (unless you use the deadline argument and the gRPC C++ async API).

Rather, it stops listening for new connections, stops accepting new calls, fails requested-but-not-yet-accepted calls. If you want to fail or terminate your calls at shutdown, you can do it at application-level code as you've done above.

I would just recommend that instead of using a global variable, you should use a member function of your `StreamServiceImpl` class so that you can support multiple services running in the same process if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ServerContext::IsCancelled` as a breaking/termination criteria in streaming APIs. I changed `GetCurrentTemperature(...)` as follows (just replaced  `g_ServerIsNotDead` with `!context_->IsCancelled()`) and it worked:

```
Status StreamServiceImpl::GetCurrentTemperature(ServerContext *context_,
                                                const UpdateInterval *request_,
                                                ServerWriter<Temperature> *stream_) {
  auto currentTemp = 100.0f;
  while(!context_->IsCancelled) {
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThreadId() << currentTemp << "farenheit.";
    Temperature message;
    message.set_temperature(currentTemp);
    stream_->Write(message);
    QThread::sleep(2);
    currentTemp += 1.0f;
  }
  return Status::OK;
}
```